# mod_rewrite - redirect a page to index

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm looking prevent people from accessing login URLs on certain servers.

Ideally I want a solution **without** having to reference the domain (there are many domains, and many server environments), and I'd like to put the rule within the global httpd.conf, rather than individual vhosts.

I've tried all kinds of mod_rewrite, to no avail, or terrible performance, eg;

```
RewriteRule ^/login$ /index.php [R,L]
RewriteRule ^login/?$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

One caveat is that it needs to work with my URL rewrites;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

..and in short, I want these;

```
http://mysite.co.uk/login
http://mysite.co.uk/index.php/login
```

to go here;

```
http://mysite.co.uk/
```

Comment: So is your problem writing the right rewrite rule or a way to place it in the httpd.conf. From your explaination `RewriteRule login/?$ / [R=301,L]` should do it. Do you have this rule in a directory-Container in your httpd.conf file?

Comment: My problem is writing the right rewrite rule, and also where to put it in the global conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should redirect the examples you provided to your site root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(index.php/)?login/?$ / [R,L]
```

As long as you place them before your existing rules, they should do what you want.

Comment: I can make that work via a local MAMP setup. What I can't figure out is how to move that login rewrite to httpd.conf, whilst retaining individual vhost files.

Comment: I think you have 2 options but both require editing each vhost configuration. First option: just use a simple `Include /path/to/general_rewrite_config` in the vhosts. Second option: put the rewrite rules in the global file in a directory Container, that is in the root path of all vhosts(only works in that case) `<Directory "/var/www"> 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On ....` and use `RewriteEngine on 
RewriteOptions inherit` in the vhost container.

Comment: Got it. The bit that threw me was "RewriteOptions inherit". I thought that it wouldn't matter since my existing rewrites were already working, but the login rewrite was getting ignored. Set it up with @arco444 snippet, and put in <Directory> as per other suggestion.